# How to integrate multiple Google account in my iPhone app without invalidating other accounts

Tags: ios, iphone, google-signin, google-authentication, googlesigninaccount

My iPhone app needs multiple Google account to be linked to app. I have integrated and successfully implemented Google Sign In SDK for iOS. Now my problem is that when I add another Google account, My previous account’s refresh token becomes invalid. When I delete and reinstall the app, It can add another Google account without any problem. Please suggest how to link/sign in multiple Google accounts to my iPhone app without invalidating previous account’s refresh tokens.